# Reuse constructors for multiple trait implementations

Tags: scala

Right now I'm writing a lot of code like the following example, but the `apply` methods are almost equal, the only thing that changes is the resulting class. Would it be possible to use the same apply method to instantiate different implementations of a `trait`?

```scala
trait Base {
  def name: Option[String]
  def value: Int
}

case class AnImplementatation(override val name: Option[String]) extends Base {
  override def value: Int = name.map(_.length).getOrElse(0)
}

object AnImplementatation {
  def apply(name: String): AnImplementatation = AnImplementatation(Some(name))
}


case class AnotherImplementatation(override val name: Option[String]) extends Base {
  override def value: Int = name.map(_.length).getOrElse(0) * 2
}

object AnotherImplementatation {
  def apply(name: String): AnotherImplementatation = AnotherImplementatation(Some(name))
}
```

Comment: Are you using the default constructor for the `case classes` or just the `apply` method?

Comment: I need both, It'm just trying to make users life easier, and avoid writing `Some(name)` when they don't need. But for those that want to use `None` to be possible.